# jQuery dropshadow on a multi-col dropdown

Tags: jquery, css, xhtml, dropshadow

I'm trying to apply a jQuery dropshadow on my CSS dropdown menu by adapting a script for my purpose.

What I want to achieve, unsuccessfully by now, is to apply dynamically a CSS left value when I'm over a list element.

http://nlhca.steveforest.com/index.shtml - go on 'About NLHCA'

So, when I'm over e.g. 'About NLHCA' div.dropShadow inline left value goes to 0.

```
style="left: -9997px; margin: 0px; position: absolute; top: 28px; z-index: 1;">
```

to

```
style="left: 0px; margin: 0px; position: absolute; top: 28px; z-index: 1;">
```

The dropshadow script is http://nlhca.steveforest.com/Templates/js/jquery.dropshadow.js

Last thing I tried :

```
 $('#dropList ul#nav li.sub a.level1-a:hover div.dropShadow').css('left:0;');
```

Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 1):

1. What version of jQuery are you using? The latest is 1.5.2; the dropshadow plugin is written for 1.2.6 which is 3 years old.
2. That's not how you use `.css()`. This is:

   ```
   $('selector').css('left', 0); // or
   $('selector').css({left: 0});
   ```
3. Why aren't you using [plain old CSS](http://robertnyman.com/2010/03/16/drop-shadow-with-css-for-all-web-browsers/) for this?